# How can I create app icons for all supported iOS/Android sizes?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, monogame, visual-studio-mac

I need to create app icons for many different devices and resolutions on iOS/Android. I use Xamarin and Visual Studio for Mac to create applications for mobile phones and tablets.

Is it necessary to create and export every app icon one after another or is there a faster and more efficient way for creating and exporting app icons?
I want to use the same sprite for all app icon sizes.

For example, I need to create app icons of all these sizes. These are just iOS icon sizes, for Android I don't know what icon sizes are supported.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I use [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/)

Comment: I found this. You can use it in Sketch and it should work on iOS and Android. http://designersstash.com/appicontemplate/

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, AppIcons do not allow for a PDF to be set and rescaled (unlike Image Catalogs).

We are exploring options to support this, as this sounds like a nice feature to have built-into the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for command line tool then  you can follow following process to generate icons for all supported iOS Devices. If you think you still miss some, then it's as simple as adding one line command.

#### Convert: Image resize

**convert** utility is installed as part of ImageMagick.

```
brew install imagemagick
```

#### Create custom script to generate iOS icons and name the file as **generateiOSIcon.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
DIR=$(dirname $1)

#echo $DIR
#output="$DIR/$2"
#echo $output

#20x20
convert -resize 20x20! $1  "$DIR/Icon_20.png";
convert -resize 40x40! $1  "$DIR/Icon_20@2x.png";
convert -resize 60x60! $1  "$DIR/Icon_20@3x.png";


#29*29
convert -resize 29x29! $1  "$DIR/Icon_29.png";
convert -resize 58x58! $1  "$DIR/Icon_29@2x.png";
convert -resize 87x87! $1  "$DIR/Icon_29@3x.png";

#40x40
convert -resize 40x40! $1  "$DIR/Icon_40.png";
convert -resize 80x80! $1  "$DIR/Icon_40@2x.png";
convert -resize 120x120! $1  "$DIR/Icon_40@3x.png";

#60x60
convert -resize 60x60! $1  "$DIR/Icon_60.png";
convert -resize 120x120! $1  "$DIR/Icon_60@2x.png";
convert -resize 180x180! $1  "$DIR/Icon_60@3x.png";

#76x76
convert -resize 76x76! $1  "$DIR/Icon_76.png";
convert -resize 152x152! $1  "$DIR/Icon_76@2x.png";
convert -resize 228x228! $1  "$DIR/Icon_76@3x.png";

#167x167
convert -resize 167x167! $1  "$DIR/Icon_167.png";
```

#### Make script executable

- > chmod =x generateiOSIcon.sh
- > ln -s /path/generateiOSIcon.sh /usr/local/bin/generateiOSIcon

#### Generating icon for iOS

You will first need App icon of size 1024x1024 and run following command

> generateiOSIcon.sh /path/image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

There are a few web-apps out there (as well as desktop apps and Photoshop/Sketch/MaxOS-Automater scripts) that do this. The mess is figuring out which icon sizes we *really* need to be adding because all of these will give you multiple icon sizes (and some of them HTML), but the quality of the output and relevance of the tags vary (ie, they might be using deprecated meta-tags). That said, here are a few I have bookmarked:

- http://www.favicomatic.com/
- https://realfavicongenerator.net/
- https://appicon.co/bmc.xyz/l/appiconmac
- https://www.favicon-generator.org/

Comment: Photoshop CC no longer has the precision required to downscale from the maximum size of 1024pt. No idea why Adobe removed this feature, but it is a giant pain.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of online tool out there where you put largest icon size (1024x1024) and it will generate all resized icons for you e.g. https://www.iconcutter.com